# Can I prevent automatic updates to block states?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

creating a custom resource pack for a server. With the elimination of metadata, the only option to add extra models and textures is to use blockstates, however for that texture to remain the same the blockstate can't change.

Ex: I want to set a block to be a daylight sensor with `power=5`. How do I keep the power value at 5 even though the sun and light levels will continuously change? This also applied to other blockstates. Can I keep an item's block states constant even as things like light or time would normally update it?

Comment: Do you need there to be a daylight cycle?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need there to be a daylight cycle, use `/gamerule doDaylightCycle false` when the sensor has the power you need, and it will stay that way as light won't change around it. Otherwise, you could put it in a closed environment, where you can control the light using torches and such.